# How to store qrcode(image) generated in the application folder

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessoryview

I want to store the generated  qrcode to be store in my application folder. Then use it as an accessory view for a cell in UITableView.

```
-(void)generateQRCode
{
    NSError *err;    
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [dict setValue:[Utility customerID] forKey:@"customerID"];
    [dict setValue:serverPath.text forKey:@"serverPath"];

    NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&err];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];

    [filter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];
    [filter setValue:@"Q" forKey:@"inputCorrectionLevel"];

    qrcodeImage = filter.outputImage;

    _imgQRCode.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:qrcodeImage];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPaths = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filepath = [documentPaths stringByAppendingString:@"qrcodeImage.png"];
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imgQRCode.image);
    [pngData writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: create view's image programmatically and save it in to document directory

Answer (score 0):

This func will return you path of documents dir.

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
return documentsDirectory}
```

You can save your image in documents dir using this code  :

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "example.png") {
if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("copy.png")
    data.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)
}}
```

After saving your image you can reload your tableview and configure the cell . Let me know if you dont know how to config accessory view.

Comment: UIImagePNGRepresentation returns nil. Is there any issue with this?

Comment: How to configure it to accessory view.

Comment: do u have image added in your project that you are trying to convert to data ? what name are you using instead of example.png?

Comment: cell.accessoryView  = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "example.png"))

Comment: the image is a QRCode which is generated at runtime. So i wanted to store it into documents directory and then use it for accessory view.

Comment: so pass that image to UIImagePNGRepresentation("Your QRCode's UIImage")

Comment: i am adding the code in the question.can you please tell me.am i doing it correct

Comment: yes look ok !! so it is saving in the documents directory now?

Comment: yes. Now i want to retrieve it and give it to accessory view.